# How can access, Listbox CustomItem datacontext in code behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext, listboxitem

How to access Question Entity in QuestionControl ?

```
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionEntityList}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <my:QuestionControl x:Name="diskInfo" DataContext={?}/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understand your question right. but when the listbox itemssource is a collection of questionentities then the datacontext  for each item is the questionentity. so for every item the listbox create a questioncontrol with the datacontext set to questionentity.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionEntityList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <my:QuestionControl />//one questioncontrol for each item in the collection, the dataconext is set to this item automatically
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Comment: sorry my bad english. ok for each entity item bind for each QuestionControl item. want to do,access binded entity object in QuestionControl(code behind).

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem.
i try access bound object(entity) in UserControl initialize method and datacontext allways return null.
i try usercontrol loaded method finally access entiy in DataContext :S

Sorry my very poor english...